# HTML Page convert to php to use it as homepage for Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, page-load-time

I want to use a static page for the homepage for faster load times. (In Wordpress)

But after the converting HTML to PHP with an online converter, it failed, I get only a 500 Issue Code and in the source code is nothing.

Comment: _"converting HTML to PHP"_ ? What does the converter do? Just changing the extention to "php"? Why using wordpress at all when everything is static anyway??

Comment: Wordpress because I use woocommerce - only homepage should be static and with html to php converter : https://codebeautify.org/html-to-php-converter you can see it yourself - set in load google.com and you'll see

Comment: why don't you just put a `<?php ?>` on top of your html and rename it to `*.php`? No need for that 'converter' (that also puts a wrong `<? php` at the start)

Answer (score 1):

There's no point of converting your static HTML page to PHP, unless you want to add some content that's frequently updated (for example posts in your blog).

If you want to create a dynamic website, then you should consider writing it in PHP (you can rename your file's extension, no further conversion is required since every line of PHP code is positioned in between `<?php` and `?>` tags). For example: if your page is called `index.html`, you can simply change its extension to `index.php` and it will work fine.

BUT! You'll need a server (or a virtual server) to run your PHP scripts (simply opening the PHP file will result in showing HTML and pieces of PHP code instead of executing it).

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to convert HTML to PHP?

The PHP is generally used to generate HTML pages..

And even at the page load level, a PHP page will have to generate the HTML to be output, while an HTML code already written will only need to be read by the server and served to the client.

So I think you read some article about someone who is not very experienced in the industry.. :-)